# Apply a split scheme with external tuple on pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame of user_id and a number between 0  to 1, and I want to join it with a scheme as following ( If hash_number between 0 and 0.5 then test, else control):

```
import pandas as pd

split_data = pd.DataFrame([(1, 0.95),
                           (2, 0.21),
                           (3, 0.52),
                           (4, 0.89)],
                          columns=('user_id', 'hashed_number'))

split_scheme = [(0, 0.5, 'test'), (0.50, 1, 'control')] #could be more than 2 groups
```

I would like to tell which user belongs to which group as following:

```
desired_split_data = pd.DataFrame([(1, 0.95, 'control'),
                                  (2, 0.21, 'test'),
                                  (3, 0.52, 'control'),
                                  (4, 0.89, 'control')],
                                  columns=('user_id', 'hashed_number', 'group'))
```

Any help on this would be amazing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) for match values and set new groups values by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
for s, e, g in split_scheme:
    m = split_data['hashed_number'].between(s, e)
    split_data.loc[m, 'group'] = g
print (split_data)
   user_id  hashed_number    group
0        1           0.95  control
1        2           0.21     test
2        3           0.52  control
3        4           0.89  control
```

Comment: nice! be aware `between` is inclusive by default, so a user might end up in a different group depending on the order of the groups in `split_scheme`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.Series.map(...)`:

```py
split_data['group']=split_data['hashed_number'].map(lambda x: next(el[2] for el in split_scheme if (el[0]<=x) and (el[1]>x)))
```

Outputs:

```py
   user_id  hashed_number    group
0        1           0.95  control
1        2           0.21     test
2        3           0.52  control
3        4           0.89  control
```